# Why Select 77C works and not C77 in Sql

Tags: sql, database

If I write `select 77C` the output is

```
C
77
```

But if I write

```
select C77
```

The output is 
  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'C77'.

Why is the  behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Your DBMS will translate

```
select 77C
```

By

```
select 77 AS C
```

But it can't translate `select C77` because it doesn't mean anything to him.

Answer (score 0):

`77` is a literal number so can be selected on its own, for me MSSQL assumes the trailing `C` is an alias  so I get the results you do.

For `C77`, `C` is not a valid literal & `77` is not a valid alias so it fails, these for example would work;

```
select 1 as C into #t
select C[77] from #t

select 'C'[77]
```